# Hugging Face load model --> RuntimeError: Cuda out of memory

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I found several threads that dealt with the same error message, but my case seems to be different. In the other threads I encountered, there was actually not enough memory to allocate.
I want to load a pre-trained transformer onto a GPU, but even trying to load the model results into the following error message:

`RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 734.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.78 GiB total capacity; 0 bytes already allocated; 618.50 MiB free; 0 bytes reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

I see, that there is less available memory than the model needs. Also, I checked with `nvidia-smi` and there is no other process running on that GPU. Additionally, there is a total of 15.78 GiB memory available, but in the end the reserved and allocated memory in sum is zero. So there should still be plenty of space for the model. Where is all the memory? Why it is not available?

Here is the code I used:

```
import evaluate
import jsonlines
import numpy as np
from transformers import (AutoTokenizer,
                          AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM,
                          DataCollatorForSeq2Seq,
                          Seq2SeqTrainingArguments,
                          Seq2SeqTrainer)
from datasets import Dataset
import os
os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER'] = 'PCI_BUS_ID'
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2'

MODEL_CHECKPOINT = "google/mt5-base"  # I checked and it should fit onto the GPU

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_CHECKPOINT)
# model = MT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(MODEL_CHECKPOINT)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(MODEL_CHECKPOINT).to("cuda")  # this line causes the error
```

The code is also mainly copied from the tutorial given on the Hugging Face website.

Comment: I would guess that someone or something else is already using most of your GPU memory

Comment: As I mentioned above: `nvidia-smi` shows that the GPU is completely available.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 GPU? If so, are you using the one with free memory?

Comment: I am trying to use multiple GPU. if I change `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2'` to `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2,3'` does .to("cuda") use two GPU? It seems like it is loading model only on one GPU when looking at nvidia-smi

Answer (score 2):

I managed to run your code with only one change and this python environment. Let me first share my environment.

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ----------
aiohttp                  3.8.4
aiosignal                1.3.1
async-timeout            4.0.2
attrs                    23.1.0
certifi                  2022.12.7
charset-normalizer       3.1.0
cmake                    3.26.3
datasets                 2.12.0
dill                     0.3.6
evaluate                 0.4.0
filelock                 3.12.0
frozenlist               1.3.3
fsspec                   2023.4.0
huggingface-hub          0.14.1
idna                     3.4
Jinja2                   3.1.2
jsonlines                3.1.0
lit                      16.0.2
MarkupSafe               2.1.2
mpmath                   1.3.0
multidict                6.0.4
multiprocess             0.70.14
networkx                 3.1
numpy                    1.24.3
nvidia-cublas-cu11       11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11   11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11   11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11        8.5.0.96
nvidia-cufft-cu11        10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11       10.2.10.91
nvidia-cusolver-cu11     11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusparse-cu11     11.7.4.91
nvidia-nccl-cu11         2.14.3
nvidia-nvtx-cu11         11.7.91
packaging                23.1
pandas                   2.0.1
pip                      22.0.2
protobuf                 3.20.0
pyarrow                  11.0.0
python-dateutil          2.8.2
pytz                     2023.3
PyYAML                   6.0
regex                    2023.3.23
requests                 2.29.0
responses                0.18.0
sentencepiece            0.1.98
setuptools               59.6.0
six                      1.16.0
sympy                    1.11.1
tokenizers               0.13.3
torch                    2.0.0
tqdm                     4.65.0
transformers             4.28.1
triton                   2.0.0
typing_extensions        4.5.0
tzdata                   2023.3
urllib3                  1.26.15
wheel                    0.40.0
xxhash                   3.2.0
yarl                     1.9.2
```

Then, I changed the line `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2'` to `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'`. Normally, if you have only one GPU, it should be in the slot number '0'. By the way, you can remove the lines that you updated os environments and try again. You can let your system attach GPU automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error finally myself.
It is necessary to set the visible devices before importing the transformer module.

Working:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER'] = 'PCI_BUS_ID'
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2'
import evaluate
import jsonlines
import numpy as np
from transformers import (AutoTokenizer,
                          AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM,
                          DataCollatorForSeq2Seq,
                          Seq2SeqTrainingArguments,
                          Seq2SeqTrainer)
from datasets import Dataset
```